# Alternatives to On-Premises ADFS

Tags: saml, federated-identity

I need to test SAML federation for a web application that is protected by an in-house SSO solution that can federate in SAML.

For testing purposes, I generally provision a Windows Server 2012 R2 server and configure ADDS and ADFS on it and then create a relying party trust to our web application's SSO solution (our SSO solution has a ACS URL which I use here)

Now, is there a SaaS based IDP that allows me to quickly configure a user store and SAML federation with my application. I just need to test the simple use case of user authenticating with his IDP credentials and the SAML assertion being posted to my ACS url.

I know there are many SaaS IDP solutions but need to know which one provides the simplest and least resistant path for my use case.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Voting to close, as you ask for a tool recommendation and this is considered off-topic here. However, a suggestion based on own expecience - we have a dummy console app that exposes a httplistener on a local machine and the listener only understand basic SAML flows and returns claims from preconfigured list. This allows us to debug the flow from both sides, the newly created client and the console app that mocks the provider.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I did have a doubt that this may be tagged for closing but I really am in need of the answer. Do you think I can post this any other stackexchange sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number and you want one that is quick to use, good documentation  and (hopefully) free.

I have used Azure AD, Auth0 and Okta for this kind of thing.

Sadly, SAML configuration is never easy!

Comment: Thanks @nzpcmad . I've successfully used Okta for my testing. They provide a very simple setup with good documentation.